# How to set a Django model field's default value to a function call / callable (e.g., a date relative to the time of model object creation)

Tags: django, django-models, parameters, lambda, default

**EDITED:**

How can I set a Django field's default to a function that gets evaluated each time a new model object gets created?

I want to do something like the following, except that in this code, the code gets evaluated once and sets the default to the same date for each model object created, rather than evaluating the code each time a model object gets created:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I want to create a default value for a function parameter such that it is dynamic and gets called and set each time the function is called.  How can I do that?  e.g.,

```
from datetime import datetime

def mydatetime(date=datetime.now()):
    print date

mydatetime() 
mydatetime() # prints the same thing as the previous call; but I want it to be a newer value
```

Specifically, I want to do it in Django, e.g.,

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: The question is misworded: it has nothing to do with function parameter defaults.  See my answer.

Comment: Per @NedBatchelder's comment, I edited my question (indicated as "EDITED:") and left the original (indicated as "ORIGINAL:")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e#answer-15289517 should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Doing this `default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)` is absolutely wrong!

It gets evaluated when you start your instance of django. If you are under apache it will probably work, because on some configurations apache revokes your django application on every request, but still you can find you self some day looking through out your code and trying to figure out why this get calculated not as you expect.

The right way of doing this is to pass a callable object to default argument. It can be a datetime.today function or your custom function. Then it gets evaluated every time you request a new default value.

```
def get_deadline():
    return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=20)

class Bill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bills')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=get_deadline)
```

Comment: If my default is based on the value of another field in the model, is it possible to pass that field as a parameter as in something like `get_deadline(my_parameter)`?

Comment: @YPCrumble this should be a new question!

Comment: Nope. That's not possible. You will have to use some different approach to do it.

Comment: How do you remove the `deadline` field again while also deleting the `get_deadline` function? I have removed a field with a function for a default value, but now Django crashes on startup after removing the function. I could manually edit the migration, which would be ok in this case, but what if you simply changed the default function, and wanted to remove the old function?

Comment: `default=datetime.today` is not working for DJango version 3.2, My database is MySQL and running your code still setting default value to None.

Answer (score 180):

The question is misguided. When creating a model field in Django, you are not defining a function, so function default values are irrelevant:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```

This last line is not defining a function; it is invoking a function to create a field in the class.

In this case `datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)` will be evaluated once, and stored as the default value.

**PRE Django 1.7**

Django [lets you pass a callable as the default][1], and it will invoke it each time, just as you want:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```

**Django 1.7+**

Please note that since Django 1.7, usage of lambda as default value is not recommended (c.f. @stvnw comment). The proper way to do this is to declare a function **before** the field and use it as a callable in default_value named arg:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# default to 1 day from now
def get_default_my_datetime():
    return datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateTimeField(default=get_default_my_date)
```

More information in the @simanas answer below
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: Thanks @NedBatchelder.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize that 'default' could take a callable.  And now I see how my question was indeed misguided regarding function invocation vs function definition.

Comment: Note that for Django>=1.7 the use of lambdas is not recommended for field options because they are incompatible with migrations. Ref: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#default), [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22351)

Comment: Please uncheck this answer, as it is wrong for Djange>=1.7. The answer by @Simanas is absolutely correct and should therefore be accepted.

Comment: How does this work with migrations? Do all old objects get a date based on the time of migration? Is it possible to set a different default to be used with migrations?

Comment: What if I want to pass some parameter to `get_default_my_date`?

Comment: My migration looks like `('secret_key', models.CharField(default=core.models.models.getsecretkey, help_text='Hex-encoded secret key to generate totp tokens.', max_length=32, unique=True, validators=[django_otp.util.hex_validator])),` and throws the exception: `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'getsecretkey'`. Why is migrate looking for `getsecretkey()` in `django.db.models` instead of `core.models.models` per the migration?

Comment: This doesn't work with migrations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496655/django-migration-default-value-callable-generates-identical-entry and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields

Answer (score 8):

There's an important distinction between the following two DateTimeField constructors:

```
my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If you use `auto_now_add=True` in the constructor, the datetime referenced by my_date is "immutable" (only set once when the row is inserted to the table).

With `auto_now=True`, however, the datetime value will be updated every time the object is saved.

This was definitely a gotcha for me at one point. For reference, the docs are here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: You've got your definitions of auto_now and auto_now_add mixed up, it's the other way round.

Comment: @MichaelBates better now?

Comment: `default=datetime.today` is not working for DJango version 3.2, My database is MySQL and running your code still setting default value to None.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you may need to access model data after creating a new user model.

Here is how I generate a token for each new user profile using the first 4 characters of their username:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
class Profile(models.Model):
    auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=13, default=None, null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User) # this is called after a User model is saved.
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: # only run the following if the profile is new
        new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        new_profile.create_auth_token()
        new_profile.save()

def create_auth_token(self):
    import random, string
    auth = self.user.username[:4] # get first 4 characters in user name
    self.auth_token =  auth + ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(3, 5)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that directly; the default value is evaluated when the function definition is evaluated. But there are two ways around it.

First, you can create (and then call) a new function each time.

Or, more simply, just use a special value to mark the default. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def mydatetime(date=None):
    if datetime is None:
        datetime = datetime.now()
    print datetime
```

If `None` is a perfectly reasonable parameter value, and there's no other reasonable value you could use in its place, you can just create a new value that's definitely outside the domain of your function:

```
from datetime import datetime

class _MyDateTimeDummyDefault(object):
    pass

def mydatetime(date=_MyDateDummyTimeDefault):
    if datetime is _MyDateDummyTimeDefault:
        datetime = datetime.now()
    print datetime

del _MyDateDummyTimeDefault
```

In some rare cases, you're writing meta-code that really does need to be able to take absolutely anything, even, say, `mydate.func_defaults[0]`. In that case, you have to do something like this:

```
def mydatetime(*args, **kw):
    if 'datetime' in kw:
        datetime = kw['datetime']
    elif len(args):
        datetime = args[0]
    else:
        datetime = datetime.now()
    print datetime
```

Comment: Note that there's no reason to actually instantiate the dummy value class - just use the class itself as the dummy value.

Comment: You CAN do this directly, just pass in the function instead of the result of the function call. See my posted answer.

Comment: No you can't. The result of the function isn't the same type of thing as the normal parameters, so it can't reasonably be used as a default value for those normal parameters.

Comment: Well yes, if you pass in an object instead of a function it will raise an exception. The same is true if you pass a function into a parameter expecting a string. I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: It's relevant because his `myfunc` function is made to take (and print) a `datetime`; you've changed it so it can't be used that way.

Comment: I wasn't aware we weren't allowed to change the way the function is used. My way works just fine, it just requires you to pass a function instead of a date, which is just as (or more) elegant than taking a placeholder value.

Comment: It's not even close to as elegant. My solution leaves the API as it is; your replaces it with something unusual and unpythonic. That's why you see code like mine all over the standard library, and code like yours nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the function in as a parameter instead of passing in the result of the function call.

That is, instead of this:

```
def myfunc(datetime=datetime.now()):
    print datetime
```

Try this:

```
def myfunc(datetime=datetime.now):
    print datetime()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because now the user can't actually pass a parameter—you'll try to call it as a function and throw an exception. In which case you might as well just take no params and `print datetime.now()` unconditionally.

Comment: Try it. You're not passing a date, you're passing the datetime.now function.

Comment: Yes, the default is passing the `datetime.now` function. But any user who passes a non-default value will be passing a datetime, not a function. `foo = datetime.now(); myfunc(foo)` will raise `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`. If I actually wanted to use your function, I'd have to do something like `myfunc(lambda: foo)` instead, which is not a reasonable interface.

Comment: I don't think its unreasonable to have an interface which requires a passed in function. The user would have to pass in a date-generating thing, not a date. So lambda: datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1), for the example.

Comment: I don't even know what to say to that. Nobody's going to expect an interface like that, or like it, or remember how to use it. It's just silly.

Comment: Interfaces which accept functions are not unusual. I could start naming examples from the python stdlib, if you like.

Comment: Yes, higher-order functions take functions. Date functions take dates. `time.strftime`, for example, does not take a function that returns a time, nor does `str.__add__` take a function that returns a string.

Comment: The question being asked here was to generate a value to populate a date field, not a "date function". I would agree, if you were writing a date library, but that's not this.

Comment: He's clearly trying to write an everyday, ordinary function with an everyday, ordinary interface, except that he wants the default to be something dynamic. You've replaced it with something different that can't be used the same way. Do you really think the `models.DateTimeField` interface expects (or should expect) a function that returns a date, instead of a date?

Comment: No, I don't think that. I don't really care what the actual default DateTimeField behavior is, you'll notice neither of our solutions would work easily there, since we both need to change the behavior of that object (your solution to interpret the placeholder value, mine to accept a function.) And if you're going to be overriding that behavior anyway, then you can make your interface expect whatever you'd like.

Comment: Django already accepts a callable exactly as this question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `get_my_datetime` without `()` which returns the current date and time (+1 day) to [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) as [a default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) as shown below. *Don't set `get_my_datetime()` with `()` because the default date and time become when the Django server starts  (Unchanged) and you should use Django's [timezone.now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) because Python's [datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) cannot save [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) correctly in database when [TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) which is default in `settings.py`:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

def get_my_datetime(): # ↓ Don't use "datetime.now()"
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=get_my_date)             
                        # Don't set "get_my_datetime()" ↑
```

And as your code, don't set `datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)` because the default date and time become when the Django server starts (Unchanged):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # default to 1 day from now              # ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Don't set ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
    my_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```