# django's timezone.now does not show the right time

Tags: django, django-timezone

My server is located in London.

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_TZ = True
```

But when I execute this:

```
from django.utils import timezone

print timezone.now().hour
```

the code prints London's time. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 16, 12, 28, 52, 797923, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Interesting... `tzinfo = <UTC>`. So maybe it prints not a London time, but UTC's +0 time? Anyway, is there any way to make Django show Moscow time?

Also when I render template with `now = timezone.now()`

`{{ now.hour }}` prints 12 (London time)

`{{ now|date:"G" }}` prints 16 (Moscow time)

Comment: Are you sure the correct settings are loaded? Check with `from django.conf import settings; print settings.TIME_ZONE`

Comment: @DanielHepper, it prints `Europe/Moscow`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

See question #2 in the ["Usage" section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage).

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Since the doc above also talks about a best practice, including an excerpt below:

> How can I obtain the local time in the current time zone?
>
> Well, the first question is, do you really need to?
>
> You should only use local time when you’re interacting with humans,
> and the template layer provides filters and tags to convert datetimes
> to the time zone of your choice.
>
> Furthermore, Python knows how to compare aware datetimes, taking into
> account UTC offsets when necessary. It’s much easier (and possibly
> faster) to write all your model and view code in UTC. So, in most
> circumstances, the datetime in UTC returned by
> django.utils.timezone.now() will be sufficient.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to set auto_add_now as localtime? Thank you very much!

Comment: A little late, but this should work:

created = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))

Comment: @jeverling Since Django 1.7 it's better not to use lambda in model defaults (it's not supported by migrations). In this case you should define a function and then pass it as a callable as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12654998)

Comment: I have a doubt..after going through the 'usage link' in the answer, now I feel that I should use default TIME_ZONE ie. UTC in settings.py. So my model's DateTimeField in auto_now_add will use UTC field and everywhere even in code I should use UTC time. Only for rendering time in template, I should use filters/tags to convert UTC to local time. Is my thinking right that I should not change default TIME_ZONE in settings.py..Please clarify whether I am understanding the correct thing or not.

Comment: Very late, but I hard disagree with the recommendation of working purely in UTC until human display. Many times you want to query based on what the user's "day" was 0-24 in local time. It is mentally very hard to reason what the query should look like in pure UTC time when each user sits in a different TZ.

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.utils import timezone
time = timezone.localtime()
```

It will give your local time that whatever your TIME_ZONE set to.

```
time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) # same result, but it is redundant.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it works in the template but not in the view python code is somewhat in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE

"..... this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms."

This is why `{{ now|date:"G" }}` prints 16 (Moscow time) prints the Moscow time!

Another note is `timezone.now()` in a normally configured Django app will pick up whatever `TIME_ZONE` is set to in the settings ('America/New_York' in example below). But can be overridden as well (see below to Paris for example in a middleware or directly in a view for that request)

```
In [27]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

Out[27]: datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 23, 1, 53, 49, 793743, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)

In [29]: timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))

In [30]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

Out[30]: datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 23, 7, 54, 19, 21898, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

Answer (score 1):

django's use_tz = True returns datetime object in  timezone. if set to false, it uses system default (locale) time which is naïve.
I performed a small experiment to clarify this confusion

test1: when
use_tz = true; timezone= us/eastern; system timezone: UTC+5:30

```
datetime.datetime.today() # returned naive datetime with locale time
timezone.now() returned # UTC
timezone.localtime() # returned us/eastern
```

test2: when
use_tz = true; timezone= us/eastern; system timezone: UTC-5

```
datetime.datetime.today() # returned naive datetime in with locale time
timezone.now() # returned UTC timezone
timezone.localtime() # in US/eastern timezone
```

test3: when
use_tz = False; timezone= us/eastern; system timezone: UTC-5

```
timezone.now() # returned naive datetime with system time
timezone.localtime() # returned traceback ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

test4: when
use_tz = False; timezone= UTC; system timezone: UTC+5:30

```
datetime.datetime.today() # returned naive datetime in system timezone
timezone.now() # returned naive datetime in system timezone
timezone.localtime() # returned traceback
```