# How to access model field value from within the model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to know, how to pass one field value to another within a single model. I need to filter `Rating` objects to get average rating of a product and I want it to be in `ProductStat` with other future statistics.

My attempt at filtering, which won't let me make a migration because of some `"Models aren't loaded yet"` appregistry error but if I comment out the `avgRating` it works.

```
class ProductStat(models.Model):
   productID = models.ForeignKey('Product')
   avgRating = models.IntegerField(
      default = Rating.objects.filter(product=productID).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
      )

class Rating(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
   rating = models.IntegerField(default = 3)
```

So my question is: how do I make `ProductStat.avgRating` filter ratings by `ProductStat.product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your models file is interpreted `Rating` model does not exists. Also, you shouldn't use fuctions as default value, use a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111255/3945375) instead.

```
def avg_rating():
    return Rating.objects.filter(product=productID).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']

class ProductStat(models.Model):
   productID = models.ForeignKey('Product')
   avgRating = models.IntegerField(
      default = avg_rating
      )
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654998/3945375) can help. You can also check [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654998/3945375) for this in Django's page.

---

If you need to use values from the currennt `ProductStat` object you could use a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/). In your *models.py*:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class ProductStat(models.Model):
   productID = models.ForeignKey('Product')
   avgRating = models.IntegerField()


def set_avg_rating(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    avg = Rating.objects.filter(product=instance.productID).aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
    instance.avgRating = avg

pre_save.connect(set_avg_rating, sender=ProductStat)
```

Comment: It works for `makemigration` and `sqlmigrate`, but when I call `migrate`, I get error `NameError: name 'productID' is not defined`

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see you were using a variable there, I just coy/paste this from your question, give me a chance to edit this.

Comment: Yes, now it works! thank you so much! (you saved my bachelor thesis)

Comment: @Zygro That's funny because I can not finish mine. Good for you.

Comment: Well, there is still matter of updating (only after a manual save, will look into it later) and I fiddled around with the thing a bit and I don't really remember what I did...