# How to remove a default value function in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

In a comment to [this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289517/1031534) I asked how to remove a field with a default value function. To sum up, the example code is:

```
def get_deadline():
    return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=20)

class Bill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bills')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=get_deadline)
```

and my question to the code is:

> How do you remove the `deadline` field again while also deleting the
>   `get_deadline` function? I have removed a field with a function for a
>   default value, but now Django crashes on startup after removing the
>   function. I could manually edit the migration, which would be ok in
>   this case, but what if you simply changed the default function, and
>   wanted to remove the old function?

I ended up removing the default part of the migration that referred to it, but how do you remove it nicely?

The only way I can think of is to squash the migrations, such that the migration using the function disappears, but that is not always an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the documentation from [Historical Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#historical-models):

> References to functions in field options such as `upload_to` and `limit_choices_to` and model manager declarations with managers having `use_in_migrations = True` are serialized in migrations, **so the functions and classes will need to be kept around for as long as there is a migration referencing them**. Any custom model fields will also need to be kept, since these are imported directly by migrations.
>
> .....
>
> To remove old references, you can **squash migrations** or, if there aren’t many references, **copy them into the migration files**.

Using a method to get the value of `default` field option is same as what is described for `upload_to` field. The documentation itself provide two options to you if you want to remove the method:

1. Squash migrations - if you don't need those anymore
2. Edit migration file: Copy functions to migration files and edit the reference in migration.

---

**Updates from comments:**

In Step 2 of *Edit migration file*, I have just included the way described in the documentation. How exactly you edit the migration is your choice. You could copy the function in the migration file and edit the reference or you could just remove the default field from the migration file, or you could use another function from a different file.

Comment: Or as per @Alasdair's answer: 3. Edit the migrations to use a different (or no) default

Comment: I would say both the answers suggest only two steps 1) squashing the migration 2) editing the migration. How exactly you edit the migrations is your choice. You could copy the function there and edit the reference. Or, you can just remove the default field from there, or you can use another function from somewhere else. :)

Comment: I have added my comments in the answer.

Comment: I'd prefer if the second step was clarified in the update section

Comment: @beruic: It is already clarified and explained. You don't really need to add step 2 again in the answer.

Comment: I know. I'm just worried that readers will miss it. Perhaps you can make the "Update from comments:" part bold instead to emphasize its importance, and make the first words in the text "In step 2..." instead of "In second step..." so the number is made clear.

Comment: I updated the answer with emphasis and also changed the language a bit.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've pretty much figured out the answer for yourself. Before you remove the `get_deadline` function, you must remove it from any migrations that use it. There are two ways to do this:

1. editing the migrations that use `get_deadline` to use a different default.
2. squashing migrations to remove the migrations that refer to `get_deadline`.

Comment: Or as per @AKS' answer: 3. Copy functions to migration files and edit the reference in migration

Answer (score 0):

> How do you remove the deadline field again while also deleting the get_deadline function?

I think removing both at the same time (i.e. “while” doing the other) is *not* the correct way to do it. Instead:

- Add a migration to remove the field. Deploy that migration as revision N.
- Confirm that nothing is using the function any more.
- In revision N+M (i.e., a later revision) remove the unused function.

That way, the database will match the state of the code, because the migrations are part of that code state: When you migrate your database back to the state as of revision N, the function will be there. When you migrate your database to the state as of revision N+M, you won't need the function any more.

Comment: This will not work. The function will still be referenced in earlier revisions.

Comment: By "revisions" I mean "migrations" :)

Answer (score -3):

My straight forward answer will be deleting the `sqlite3.db` and delete all the migrations except the `__init__.py` in the migrations folder in each app.

Then again do python

```
$manage.py makemigrations
$python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: What if I am on a live system with data that I cannot afford losing on a MySQL or PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Then coding in you live data is simply a bad idea. I guess

Comment: Well, migrations wouldn't be necessary at all if if should not be possible to upgrade live data. And if you cannot upgrade live data, you cannot evolve your software.

Comment: But depending on migration files for database migration is looking like a joke to me.

Comment: Then come up with a better way :)