# How to create a field in MySQL that get data from the callable function in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, parameters, django-forms

How can I set a django field that gets data from a function depending on other fields?
Let me explain using the following example.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    def testType(self):
        return str(self.__class__.__name__)
    sources = models.CharField(default= testType, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

In this case, if I go to django front-end interface and hit "add Test", I can see a box for 'sources' to fill out. This is not the way I wanted.
I want: 1. a field named 'sources' in the back-end MySQL database, 2. No box for 'sources' to fill out in the "add Test" form, and 3. The 'sources' field will get data as soon as I add a new record.

Any suggestion that can help me to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a Django model field's default value to a function call / callable (e.g., a date relative to the time of model object creation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different things to do here to achieve what you want.

> 1. a field named 'sources' in the back-end MySQL database
> 2. The 'sources' field will get data as soon as I add a new record.

You already have that. Setting a default from a callable [does exist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#default). The problem is trying to have the default set off of self during creation.

You can achieve that by overriding the [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) on `Test`

Here is what your Test model could look like:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    sources = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        self.sources = str(self.__class__.__name__)
        super(Test, self).save()
```

Now, whenever you save (create or update) a Test model instance, it will set the sources field.

> 3. No box for 'sources' to fill out in the "add Test" form

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) show you how to select what fields you want to appear in the form. You can either use `fields` or `exclude`. It tends to be a better security practice to explicitly list what fields you want to show in a form, rather than doing it implicitly with `exclude`.

With fields:

```
class Meta: #Put this in your Test form
    model=Test
    fields = ('someField',)
```

Now, only `someField` would be rendered in your form. Only fields you put in there will be rendered, all others ignored.

With exclude:

```
class Meta: #Put this in your Test form
    model=Test
    exclude= ['sources']
```

All fields on your model will be rendered **except** `sources`

Comment: Hi Fred, sorry for my late response, I have been traveling. I am still getting error. Let me explain that. first, I called the testType function at sources this way 'sources = models.CharField(default= testType, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)'. The error message is "sampleTtype() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)". Second, I tried putting parenthesis "sources = models.CharField(default= testType(), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)". It showed me same error. Although the error goes away if I use None in the paranthesis "testType(None)", it does not work. Any more suggestion?

Comment: Hi again Fred, controlling the appearance in the form using "fields" was successful. Just to let you know, I placed 'fields' at TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) in the admin.py file and it worked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Since you are handling setting sources in the save, you don't need the default anymore. Updated my answer to remove it.

Comment: Hi Fred, while this issue is solved, it doesn't update data when I edit the entry later. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @DubarAlam is there anything I need to update my answer with, or was the problem you had elsewhere?

Comment: I got the issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you only want this done on creation of a new record, which is easily done by overriding the save method of a Django model.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    sources = models.CharField(default= testType, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, *kwargs):
        if not self.pk:                # No pk attribute if not saved to DB
            self.sources = self.testType()
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    # call parent save method

    def testType(self):
        return str(self.__class__.__name__)
```

This doesn't involve form logic at all, instead relying purely on model logic. Any time a new Test is created, it will attempt write the sources field through this method.

Comment: Hi Ian, this issue is partially solved. Now, the 'sources' field gets data as soon as I add a new record. However, it doesn't update data when I edit the entry later. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Never mind. I just removed the if statement "if not self.pk:". It works fine.