# Django migration default value callable generates identical entry

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I am adding a new field to an existing db table. it is to be auto-generated with strings.

Here is my code:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

...
Model:
    verification_token = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, default=get_random_string)
```

I generate my migration file with `./manage.py makemigrations` and a file is generated.
I verify the new file has default set to `field=models.CharField(default=django.utils.crypto.get_random_string, max_length=60)`

so all seems fine. 

Proceed with `./manage.py migrate` it goes with no error from terminal.
However when i check my table i see all the `token` fields are filled with identical values.
 
[image]

Is this something i am doing wrong?
How can i fix this within migrations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a new column is added to a table, and the column is `NOT NULL`, each entry in the column must be filled with a valid value during the creation of the column. Django does this by adding a `DEFAULT` clause to the column definition. Since this is a single default value for the whole column, your function will only be called once.

You can populate the column with unique values using a data migration. The procedure for a slightly different use-case is described [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields), but the basics of the data migrations are as follows:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def generate_verification_token(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
    for row in MyModel.objects.all():
        row.verification_token = get_random_string()
        row.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0004_add_verification_token_field'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # omit reverse_code=... if you don't want the migration to be reversible.
        migrations.RunPython(generate_verification_token, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Just add this in a new migration file, change the `apps.get_model()` call and change the dependencies to point to the previous migration in the app.

Comment: I ended up using this and cleared a few questions with Django migrations. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It maybe the token string to sort, so django will save some duplicates values. But, i'm not sure it is your main problem.

Anyway, I suggest you to handle duplicates values using `while`, then filter your model by generated token, makesure that token isn't used yet. I'll give you exampe such as below..

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def generate_token():
    token = get_random_string()
    number = 2
    while YourModel.objects.filter(verification_token=token).exists():
        token = '%s-%d' % (token, number)
        number += 1
    return token
```

in your field of `verification_token`;

```
verification_token = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, default=generate_token)
```

I also suggest you to using `unique=True` to handle duplicated values.

Comment: Although this did not work due to django migrations uses one default value for all existing rows, sent me in the right direction.