# Generate a unique key after refresh Django Admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Django Admin capabilities to add to a model a randomly generated password.
However, doing refresh to the admin's form page or after clicking "Save and add another" this random password doesn't change.

How do i force Django to re-generate a fresh password?

```
def generate_rand():
    random_bytes = urandom(64)
    return b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')

class SubClient(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                           verbose_name=_('Organization name'),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,
                        verbose_name=_('End-Client name'),)

    db_password = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=generate_rand())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pass a callable object, not the result of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289517/4974980):

```
db_password = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=generate_rand)
```

[Django documentation for `default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#default)