# Calculate due date in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am creating a "library" website using django.

Once a user has issued a book and I want to calculate a due date for it which will 3 months after the issue/present date.

How do I do it?

Comment: You ask it to *Deep Thought*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module and you can add a timedelta of 90 days very easily:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> print datetime.datetime.now()
2017-10-23 19:24:19.549670
>>> print datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
2018-01-21 19:24:21.583689
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about setting an auto-value on a database column.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e)  has the answer to your question, almost exactly. Be sure to note what version of Django you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to override the `save` method for the model which tracks the book transaction.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class BookTransaction(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if first time creating transaction (as opposed to on update)
        if not self.id:             
            self.due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(months=3)

        # call and return default save method after custom rule
        return super(Base, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```