# Django model create expire date

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to automatically create an expire date in my model based on the create date.  Say 60 days?

```
 class Something ( models.Model ):

    created = models.DateTimeField ( auto_now_add = True )
    expires = models.DateTimeField (  )
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you were going to always do it against the current day, then you could make a function that computes that 60 day diff dynamically, and put that function pointer in the `default=func_name`.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654998/2955584