# Select an expiredate field

Tags: python, django

I have created an `expiredate` field which is generated automatically based on the `registerdate` field

I've tried a regular query just like i would use for any field (it is mentioned below)

this is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField()
    expiredate = timezone.now().date() + timedelta(days= 70)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}" .format(self.user)
```

and this is the query i'm trying to use:

```
expire = UserProfile.objects.values('expiredate')
```

I simply want to select the `expiredate` and use it on my `views.py` function but the query generates an error:

```
'Cannot resolve keyword 'expiredate' into field. Choices are: course, course_id, id, phonenumber, registerdate, user, user_id'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the expire date doesn't show on the admin site. If it has anything to do with the fact that i can't use a simple query to get the value of a field from the model please explain it in the comments !

Comment: `expiratedate` is not field but just a class attribute. How are you so sure it is a field. In simple words I'll explain, Can you see it in django admin? No right. So, it's not a field.

Comment: Tell us the purpose of this field. I guess you've created your model in wrong way.

Comment: i want to use it because the users that are going to register will only have their accounts active for a period of time (70 days). and this model extends the django User model because i wanted to add some more details on the registerd users than just the ones that are given by django

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`expiredate` can be a `DateField`.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    expiredate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date() + timedelta(days= 70))
```

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Why not use `DateTimeField`?? If a user registers on 1st june at 11:00pm, the account should expire on 9 Aug at 11:00pm (exactly 70 days), not on 9Aug at 12:00am (user is loosing 11 hours of usage). @PàrísŹarka - you also give it a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Solution by @katoozi force default value to be same until application restarted.

Use callable to get correct value:

```
def get_expiredate():
    return timezone.now().date() + timedelta(days= 70)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    expiredate = models.DateField(default=get_expiredate)
```

Take a look at [How to set a Django model field's default value to a function call / callable (e.g., a date relative to the time of model object creation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e)