# duplicate Key violation in Django insert doing after Django update

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

first i update my model instance, after that i tried to insert a new data but showing

"IntegrityError('duplicate key value violates unique constraint "RFIDActivation_ActivationId_key"\nDETAIL:  Key ("ActivationId")=(6de9ed9a) already exists.\n',)"

Models.py

```
class RFIDActivation(models.Model):
    RFIDActivationId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='RFIDActivationId')
    Device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='DeviceId')
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='EmployeeId')
    ActivationId = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default=uuid4().hex[:8])
    ActivationStatus = models.CharField(max_length=1)default=None)

    class Meta:
       db_table = "RFIDActivation"
```

my serializer.py

```
class RFIDActivationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RFIDActivation
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def rfid_activation_initial(request):
     RFIDActivation.objects.filter(Employee=request.POST.get("Employee")).update(
            ActivationStatus='2',
            ActivationMessage='Abort'
        )

    rfid_activation = {
        'Employee': request.POST.get("Employee"),
        'Device': request.POST.get("Device"),
        'ActivationStatus': "0",
        'ActivationMessage': "RFID Activation Initiated"
    }
    rfid_serializer = RFIDActivationSerializer(data=rfid_activation)
    if rfid_serializer.is_valid():
        rfid_serializer.save()
```

but  rfid_serializer.save() shows exception[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD3od.png)

Previous ActivationId is using to saving the new data. ActivationId  is unique and auto generated. How can i solve this. Error is showing trying to insert after update query

view.py for working fine code only insertion.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def rfid_data_add(request):
    rfid_activation = {
        'Employee': request.POST.get("Employee"),
        'Device': request.POST.get("Device"),
        'ActivationStatus': "0",
        'ActivationMessage': "RFID Activation Initiated"
    }
    rfid_serializer = RFIDActivationSerializer(data=rfid_activation)
    if rfid_serializer.is_valid():
        rfid_serializer.save()
```

Comment: specify **`read_only=True`** in your primary key, `RFIDActivationId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='RFIDActivationId', read_only=True)`

Comment: @minglyu , while adding read_only=True , showing error
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'read_only'

Comment: @minglyu  here i am trying to update the existing details, then inserting new data.. in this case   unique key ActivationId(not primary key) showing the  duplicate key value violates unique constrain error..  but insertion with out update query is working fine

Comment: are you still facing issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In restframework, **`serializer.save()`** has different behavior based on creation and update. If you pass **instance** to serializer, it will update the object, otherwise, it will create a new one

```
@api_view(['POST', 'PUT'])
def rfid_data(request, pk):
    """
    Update or delete a rfid data.
    """

    rfid_activation = {
         ...
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        rfid_serializer = RFIDActivationSerializer(data=rfid_activation)
        if rfid_serializer.is_valid():
            rfid_serializer.save()
            return Response(rfid_serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return return Response(rfid_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # PUT is used for object update
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        rfid = RFIDActivation.objects.get(pk=pk)
        # pass instance to your serializer
        # pass partial=True to allow partial updates
        rfid_serializer = RFIDActivationSerializer(instance=rfid, data=rfid_activation, partial=True)
        if rfid_serializer.is_valid():
            rfid_serializer.save()
            return Response(rfid_serializer.data)
        return Response(rfid_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### UPDATE

`default` is calculated at **`import time`**, in your case, your default value for `activation_id` is calculated once and never change for subsequent instances.
You have to define a function, thus default callable will be updated each time on object creation, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e)

```
def activation_id_generator(self):
    return uuid4().hex[:8]

# then in your class
class RFIDActivation(models.Model):
    ...
    ActivationId = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default=activation_id_generator)
```

Comment: i am not having 2 request method, only one method is exist. i want to do update and insertion i same request.. at that case, update is working fine and after update , insertion not working fine..  unique key accepting the previous values..

Comment: @ElmaAlida It's a good convention in REST to use `POST` for creation and `PUT` for update. Take a look of the tutorial https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

Comment: @minglyu why `partial=True`? I have tried without it and it works fine.

Comment: @minglyu  , I didnt working good.. in case of POST method also showing the  erroro
"IntegrityError('duplicate key value violates unique constraint "RFIDActivation_ActivationId_key"\nDETAIL: Key ("ActivationId")=(6de9ed9a) already exists.\n',)" 
We can  insert 1 time , den when i tried to insert the same data .but showing the error...

Comment: @minglyu thank you so much  :) ... its working fine..  this is what i am looking.. you helped me a lot.. :) thank you so much