# Problem Overriding the save() method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a peculiar type of model where `table_fields` needs to set to default depending on the value of its `report_type` field.

```
class Report(models.Model):
    ALL_TABLE_FIELDS = (
        'local_ordered_date', 'card', 'country', 'customer', 'supplier',
        'amount', 'currency', 'quantity', 'quantity_unit', 'invoice_total',
        'payment_total', 'balance', 'owner', 'lost_reason', 'lost_description', 'result',
        'local_result_updated_at', 'local_delivery_deadline', 'board', 'stage', 'order_number',
        'product', 'incoterms', 'destination_port', 'loading_port', 'payment_terms',
        'other_terms'
    )
    DEFAULT_TABLE_FIELDS = {
        'OrderTrendReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                             'currency', 'stage', 'owner', 'country',
                             'local_ordered_date', 'local_delivery_deadline',
                             'order_number'),
        'RevenueTrendReport': ('card', 'customer', 'invoice_total',
                               'payment_total', 'balance', 'currency',
                               'owner', 'order_number', 'board'),
        'DealSuccessRateReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                                  'currency', 'owner', 'result',
                                  'local_result_updated_at'),
        'DealLostReasonReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                                 'currency', 'owner',
                                 'local_result_updated_at', 'lost_reason',
                                 'lost_description'),
        'OrderByCategoryReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                                  'currency', 'stage', 'owner', 'country',
                                  'local_ordered_date', 'local_delivery_deadline',
                                  'order_number')
    }

    """
    The proper way to set a field's default value to a function call/callable
    is to declare a function before the field and use it as a callable in default_value named arg
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e
    """

    class ReportType(models.TextChoices):
        # hard-coded in order to avoid ImportError and AppRegistryNotReady
        OrderTrendReport = 'OrderTrendReport', 'Order Trend report'
        RevenueTrendReport = 'RevenueTrendReport', 'Revenue Trend report'
        DealSuccessRateReport = 'DealSuccessRateReport', 'Deal Success Rate report'
        DealLostReasonReport = 'DealLostReasonReport', 'Deal Lost Reason report'
        OrderByCategoryReport = 'OrderByCategoryReport', 'Order By Category report'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    report_type = models.CharField(choices=ReportType.choices,
                                   max_length=50,
                                   default=ReportType.OrderTrendReport)
    table_fields = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50),
                              default=list)

    @property
    def all_table_fields(self):
        return self.ALL_TABLE_FIELDS

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # this will ensure that the object is new
            self.table_fields = self.DEFAULT_TABLE_FIELDS[self.report_type]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

After finishing the code for `models.py`, I went on and made a migration file. Then I edited this like so:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


def make_report_fields(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Report = apps.get_model('deal', 'Report')
    ReportTypes = ('OrderTrendReport', 'RevenueTrendReport', 'DealSuccessRateReport',
                   'DealLostReasonReport', 'OrderByCategoryReport')
    report_fields = [Report(user=user, report_type=report_type)
                     for report_type in ReportTypes
                     for user in User.objects.all()]
    Report.objects.bulk_create(report_fields)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('deal', '0059_auto_20210610_0948'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Report',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('report_type', models.CharField(choices=[('OrderTrendReport', 'Order Trend report'), ('RevenueTrendReport', 'Revenue Trend report'), ('DealSuccessRateReport', 'Deal Success Rate report'), ('DealLostReasonReport', 'Deal Lost Reason report'), ('OrderByCategoryReport', 'Order By Category report')], default='OrderTrendReport', max_length=50)),
                ('table_fields', django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=50), default=list, size=None)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(make_report_fields)
    ]
```

When I ran `python migrate deal {# of migration file}`, the table was made, with many rows corresponding to the existing users.
However, the `table_fields` were all empty.

[image: empty_table_fields]

How do I fix it so that the `table_fields` will be set to correct default according to its 'report_type'?

Comment: `bulk_create` _does not_ use the models `save` method and works on a SQL level, hence your code doesn't work as you want.

Comment: when I do  
```for user in User.objects.all():
        for report_type in ReportTypes:
            report = Report(user=user, report_type=report_type)
            report.save()``` 
 it still fills empty array

Comment: Yes, because the serialized model in the migration does not have your custom `save` method. Check my answer below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) one of the caveats of `bulk_create` is as follows:

> The model’s `save()` method will not be called, and the `pre_save` and
> `post_save` signals will not be sent.

Also custom model methods are not available in the migrations as they use a *serialized* representation of your models without them. Hence your code never uses the `save` method causing your code to not work as you want it to. Instead of relying on the `save` method why don't you simply pass the correct array yourself? Something like follows:

```
DEFAULT_TABLE_FIELDS = {
    'OrderTrendReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                         'currency', 'stage', 'owner', 'country',
                         'local_ordered_date', 'local_delivery_deadline',
                         'order_number'),
    'RevenueTrendReport': ('card', 'customer', 'invoice_total',
                           'payment_total', 'balance', 'currency',
                           'owner', 'order_number', 'board'),
    'DealSuccessRateReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                              'currency', 'owner', 'result',
                              'local_result_updated_at'),
    'DealLostReasonReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                             'currency', 'owner',
                             'local_result_updated_at', 'lost_reason',
                             'lost_description'),
    'OrderByCategoryReport': ('card', 'board', 'customer', 'amount',
                              'currency', 'stage', 'owner', 'country',
                              'local_ordered_date', 'local_delivery_deadline',
                              'order_number')
}

def make_report_fields(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Report = apps.get_model('deal', 'Report')
    ReportTypes = ('OrderTrendReport', 'RevenueTrendReport', 'DealSuccessRateReport',
                   'DealLostReasonReport', 'OrderByCategoryReport')
    report_fields = [Report(user=user, report_type=report_type, table_fields=DEFAULT_TABLE_FIELDS[report_type])
                     for report_type in ReportTypes
                     for user in User.objects.all()]
    Report.objects.bulk_create(report_fields)
```