# Django3.2 python migration not setting default value

Tags: python, django-3.2

My database is MySQL. I am trying to set default value to current date time to created_at field below in the migration code. Due to some reasons, the default value is showing nothing in the database side, likewise, is_Active is having same issue. Am I missing anything?

I meant, default value is blank in both cases. Can you please suggest?

**Approach 1**

```
class tblusers(models.Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
    #trying to set default value = now
    is_active = BooleanField(default = 0, null = True)
    #trying to set default value = 0
```

**Approach 2**

```
class tblusers(models.Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    #trying to set default value = now
    is_active = BooleanField(default = 0, null = True)
    #trying to set default value = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this:
`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Did you see this question? [How to set a Django model field's default value to a function call / callable (e.g., a date relative to the time of model object creation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e)

Comment: 0001_initial.py has this code `('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),` after changing my code as you suggested and then in the mysql database side, created_at has value None.

Comment: Without `null=True`, it can't have value `None`.